# Is there a way to combine python and perl scripts into a single exe?

Tags: python, perl, exe

I trying to combine several python scripts to an exe, which works fine. However, one of my scripts is calling a perl script, which is not a problem on my machine since I have perl installed.

Now my question: is there a way to include this perl script into my exe, so that it can run as a standalone exe, regardless if the user has perl installed or not?

For context I use subprocess to execute the perl script.

Comment: You could try [`App::Fatpacker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) but I think it requires the `perl` interpreter installed on the user's machine

Comment: See also [plenv-download](https://github.com/skaji/plenv-download) for a way to include a precompiled perl binary

Comment: [PAR Packager](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) can package an architecture-specific perl executable with your code. I don't know if it could be combined with other things in an executable.

Comment: ActiveState.com used to offer Perl Dev Kit which could create .exe from .pl and .pm. They still do I think, but maybe not for free anymore. Also take a look at https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1165708 On Windows10 you could also look into WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to run python and perl scripts directly from source without compiling.

Answer (score 2):

[staticperl](http://p3rl.org/staticperl):

> when linking statically, you can create (or embed) a single file that contains perl interpreter, […] and of course your actual program